# VM Filesystem on SSD

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ssd, filesystems, trim

If I run a Virtual Machine, and I enabled all SSD related tweaks on the Host machine (disabled journalling, enabled trim, etc) do I still need to apply the same tweaks for the Guest machine?

I could imagine that the Host OS caches writes to the Virtual Disk Image in RAM, and therefore the many small writes of a journalling system like EXT4 may be batched together into one single large write to the file, causing less damage than running on a raw disk. But those are just assumptions, so maybe someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that:

- You don't need to enable trim, the host does that.
- You do need to disable anything that causes unnecessary writes. Maybe the host does cache it, but if you can cut it out altogether that's even better.